# mariadb - join/order by clauses cause slow query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

have a small blog site, host provider runs `Server version: 5.5.5-10.3.34-MariaDB-cll-lve MariaDB Server`. The last weeks i noticed fetching the posts is slower, and it turns out the query now takes 6 seconds.

the in question query:

```
SELECT * FROM POSTS
JOIN POST_CATEGORIES on POST_CATEGORIES.CATEG_ID = POSTS.POST_CATEGORY
LEFT JOIN USERS on POSTS.POST_USERNAME = USERS.USER_USERNAME
WHERE POST_STATUS = 'ENA'
AND POST_IS_PUBLIC = 'Y'
ORDER BY POST_IS_STICKY DESC, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, POST_CREATION_DATE, now())-(POST_LIKES-POST_DISLIKES)*3600) ASC
LIMIT 0, 12;
```

if i remove the `order by` the query time drops to 0.04 sec, but obviously it is needed for proper sorting. Same effect happens if i remove the left join to `USERS`, but i would like to focus on the `order by` clause.

Table rows:

```
POSTS: 62K
POST_CATEGORIES: 20
USERS: 180
```

**Interesting finding:**

There are already indexes (primary/unique/foreign key) on the tables, but not on the columns involved, for the simplicity i am not adding them here.

But i did try adding the index:

```
INDEX `POSTS_OPTIMIZING_INDEX` (`POST_CREATION_DATE`, `POST_LIKES`, `POST_DISLIKES`) USING BTREE,
```

and `FORCE INDEX (POSTS_OPTIMIZING_INDEX)` and saw something interesting:

- on the MariaDB, literally no difference.
- on mysql community server `Server version: 5.7.20 MySQL Community Server (GPL)` that i have home, the query duration from 6 seconds went down to 0.12sec, which is definitely acceptable.

Any suggestions on optimizing the SQL, or tuning mariadb?

**EDIT**

the table definitions:

POSTS:

```
CREATE TABLE `POSTS` (
  `POST_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `POST_URL_ID` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_TYPE` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_CATEGORY` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_IS_PUBLIC` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_IS_STICKY` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_FREE_TEXT` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_IMAGE_FILE` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_VIDEO_URL` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_IS_FROM_USER` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_USERNAME` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_CREATION_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `POST_STATUS` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ENA',
  `POST_LIKES` int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  `POST_DISLIKES` int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  `POST_ADDITIONAL_INFO` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_FB_OBJ_ID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_FB_OBJ_TYPE` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_FB_IMG_LAST_CHECKED` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_FB_IMG_LAST_CHECK_RESULT` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `POST_TWITTER_OBJ_ID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`POST_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `POST_URL_ID` (`POST_URL_ID`),
  KEY `FK_POSTS_POST_CATEGORIES` (`POST_CATEGORY`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_POSTS_POST_CATEGORIES` FOREIGN KEY (`POST_CATEGORY`) REFERENCES `POST_CATEGORIES` (`CATEG_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62529 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

POST_CATEGORIES:

```
CREATE TABLE `POST_CATEGORIES` (
  `CATEG_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CATEG_URL_NAME` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CATEG_NAME` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CATEG_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

USERS:

```
CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_MAIL_ADDRESS` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_USERNAME` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_PASSWORD` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_CREATION_DATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `USER_LAST_LOGIN_DATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_FROM_FB` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_FB_MAIL_ADDRESS` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_FB_FULL_NAME` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_SPECIAL` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_ACCT_STATUS` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'ENA',
  `USER_POSTS_COUNT` int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  `USER_NAME` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_QUOTE` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_ABOUT_MYSELF` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_WEBSITE` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_FB` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_TWITTER` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_LOCATION` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_BIRTHDAY` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_PROFILE_PIC` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_PROFILE_PIC_FROM_FB` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `USER_USERNAME` (`USER_USERNAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=188 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

the `EXPLAIN`:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT * FROM POSTS
    -> JOIN POST_CATEGORIES on POST_CATEGORIES.CATEG_ID = POSTS.POST_CATEGORY
    -> LEFT JOIN USERS on POSTS.POST_USERNAME = USERS.USER_USERNAME
    -> WHERE POST_STATUS = 'ENA'
    -> AND POST_IS_PUBLIC = 'Y'
    -> ORDER BY POST_IS_STICKY DESC, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, POST_CREATION_DATE, now())-(POST_LIKES-POST_DISLIKES)*3600) ASC
    -> LIMIT 0, 12;
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | POSTS           | ALL    | FK_POSTS_POST_CATEGORIES | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                           | 61407 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | POST_CATEGORIES | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY | 4       | MY_DB.POSTS.POST_CATEGORY |     1 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | USERS           | ALL    | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                           |   178 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

and removing the 2 joins:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT * FROM POSTS
    -> WHERE POST_STATUS = 'ENA'
    -> AND POST_IS_PUBLIC = 'Y'
    -> ORDER BY POST_IS_STICKY DESC, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, POST_CREATION_DATE, now())-(POST_LIKES-POST_DISLIKES)*3600) ASC
    -> LIMIT 0, 12;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | POSTS | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 61407 | Using where; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

TIA

Comment: can you share tables definition, sample values and field types?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: hi guys, i updated the question with the requested info.

Comment: positive update: i changed the collation of USERS table to match the POSTS, and now the query duration dropped from 6sec to 1sec! i had initially created the schema with `utf8_unicode_ci` but to support emojis i changed only specific tables/fields to utf8mb4_unicode_ci, and seems the JOIN `POSTS.POST_USERNAME = USERS.USER_USERNAME` was affected by this collation mismatch. 1sec could definitely take some improvements, but from my side the performance now is more than acceptable.

Comment: View profile for contact info and get in touch for additional performance tuning, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Explode-implode" syndrome.  Rewrite the query to get the 12 rows *first*, *then* `JOIN` to the other tables.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT user_id,
                  is_sticky,
                  (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, POST_CREATION_DATE, now()) -
                     (POST_LIKES-POST_DISLIKES)*3600)  AS  metric
             FROM POSTS
             WHERE  POST_STATUS = 'ENA'
               AND  POST_IS_PUBLIC = 'Y'
             ORDER BY
                 POST_IS_STICKY DESC, metric ASC
             LIMIT  0, 12
         ) AS x
     JOIN POSTS AS p USING(user_id)
     JOIN  POST_CATEGORIES AS pc  ON pc.CATEG_ID = p.POST_CATEGORY
     LEFT JOIN  USERS AS u  ON p.POST_USERNAME = u.USER_USERNAME
     ORDER BY x.POST_IS_STICKY DESC, x.metric ASC
```

Replace the elipsis with the columns you really need.

Yes, `POSTS` is looked into a second time, but only for 12 rows, and by the PK.  Similarly, the other rows are reached into only 12 times.

Yes, the `ORDER BY` needs to be repeated.  The `LIMIT` may need repeating if the `JOIN` creates extra rows (eg, multiple categories).

Consider using

```
SELECT ...
       ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CATEG_NAME) FROM POST_CATEGORIES
              WHERE categ_id = p.post_categories ) AS Categories,
       ...
```

instead of JOINing to `POST_CATEGORIES`, especially if there are multiple categories.

This *may* help with performance, but only if it is selective enough:

```
INDEX(post_tatus, post_is_public)
```

Comment: thank you! Although the 2 joins are to low usage tables, i can see the benefits of what you are suggesting. Will come back to you later today, when i try to test your proposal.

Comment: Just implemented the change (only the sql, no indexes) and here are the results: old query: 1.15sec, new query 0.15sec !! difference is significant, cannot be happier with that processing time :) Thank you for your assistance!